# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16afa3fe0) in Reachability

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, reachability

I am using Reachability class for network status check in my iOS application, but during the unit testing i turn of the WIFI of iPhone device and run the code but i am getting a crash in Reachability class in in 'reachabilityWithAddress' function, i am stuck here why this crash is happening i am not getting any point to solve this. My code is given below, some one please help me out this. Thank in advance.

```
+ (instancetype)reachabilityWithAddress:(const struct sockaddr  *)hostAddress
 {

  SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability =    
  SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress                                                     
  (kCFAllocatorDefault, hostAddress);

Reachability* returnValue = NULL;

if (reachability != NULL)
{
    returnValue = [[self alloc] init];
    if (returnValue != NULL)
    {
        returnValue->_reachabilityRef = reachability;
    }
    else {
        CFRelease(reachability);
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a Symbolic Breakpoint? So we can see the specific line of code and inspect the problem.

Comment: Symbolic break point won’t help.  But the backtrace of the crash will.